# In java, how do I open my web browser and set a custom URL?

Tags: java, android, url, android-intent, browser

I know this can be done in Android with intents, but since those don't exist in java, I want to know if there is a way to do it.

Comment: Do you want this to happen in javascript? or in a java applet?

Comment: In a stand alone application.

Comment: from AWT you can simply do Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI("http://www.apolloss.com"));

Comment: @AmitApollo I already answer that.. ;)

Answer (score 4):

**Yes it can be done by using** `java.awt.Desktop.`

```
 import java.awt.Desktop;
 import java.net.URI;

 try{

    if(Desktop.isDesktopSupported())
    {
      Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI("http://www.google.com"));
    }

 }catch(URISyntaxException use){
 //exception handling
 }catch(IOException ioe){
 //exception handling
 }
```

Please see http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html

Comment: As a side note, `URISyntaxException` and `IOException` must be handled explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry I was trying to type it above:

using AWT you can simply do

```
      import java.awt.Desktop;
      import java.net.URI;
```

Then in your code:

```
      Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI("http://www.apolloss.com"));
```